# how to remove previous item on user clicks or any button pressed

Tags: powerpoint, slideshow

How I can add for example 10 item including text image and etc into the one slide of power point, and the slide Show start like this?

1. only the first item appears
2. on user click or any button pressed the previous item should be removed and second item placed instead of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One have to add text and image in a specific order on the slide.

Comment: Drag and drop images from your image folder.